# What is the difference between fetch and jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, fetch-api

I want to send a post request through fetch, but it does not work.

But if I do it through jQuery ajax, it succeeds.

I want to know the difference of the two way and if there is anything  wrong in my use of fetch here:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8888/news',{
    method:"post",
    data:"code=7&a=8&b=9"
}).then(function(data){
     data.json().then(function (json) {
}
```

Comment: fetch doesn't work in IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @Alex The Fetch API doesn’t work in iOS Safari (10.2) yet either http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch but it does work in every other current major browser—including desktop Safari and Edge 14+

Comment: @Alex jquery is not part of the browser, if you say `fetch` does not work then `jquery` won't _work_ either. There are fetch polyfills for browser that do not have a native implementation yet.

Comment: @t.niese, jquery is not part, because it's library, which can be used in any browser, but fetch is not. fetch is part of javascript and javascript is part of the browser.

Comment: @Alex `fetch` (unlike `Promise`) is not a javascript language feature but a _web api_ feature. But thats not my point. You can use `fetch` in browser that support `XMLHttpRequest` using a [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch). It would be the same as if you would say that you can use bluebird but no Promises in older browsers, just because they dont have a native implementation for it.

Comment: Here in 2020, the MDN site still says that `.fetch` and `.json` dont work in most everything. So, just dont use it, its rubbish!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`Fetch` specification differs from `jQuery.ajax()` in mainly two ways:

1. The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.
2. By default, fetch won't send or receive any cookies from the server, resulting in unauthenticated requests if the site relies on maintaining a user session (to send cookies, the credentials init option must be set).

Comment: Important update ([mentioned on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#differences_from_jquery.ajax)): « As of August 2018, the default credentials policy changed to same-origin. »