# Send __RequestVerificationToken with Fetch API and recieve with an [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, fetch-api

I want to submit a form through fetch. The controller action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost("new")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult NewUser(NewUserViewModel user)
{
    // code...
}
```

As you can see, I'm using ValidateAntiForgeryToken.
On the client side I've found that this jQuery code works:

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.location.pathname,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        Id: "1",
        UserName: "ajax",
        Password: "ajax",
        ConfirmPassword: "ajax",
        FullName: "ajax",
        Email: "ajax@ajax.is",
        Client: "ajax",
        Roles: ["ajax"],
        __RequestVerificationToken: document.querySelector('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').value
    },
    success: function (response) {
        alert('Tókst');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('tókst ekki');
    }
});
```

But I want to use fetch API so I made this attempt:

```
let response = await fetch(window.location.pathname, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
        Id: "1",
        UserName: "fetch",
        Password: "fetch",
        ConfirmPassword: "fetch",
        FullName: "fetch",
        Email: "fetch@fetch.is",
        Client: "fetch",
        Roles: ["fetch"],
        __RequestVerificationToken: document.querySelector('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').value
    }
});
```

The response is then handled below.
I would have thought that the fetch call is identical to the $.ajax call but it does not work.

The $.ajax call goes all the way to the action but the fetch call gets an 400 error.
The fetch call does work if I remove the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] from the action.

Does anyone know what's missing so that I can post this successfully with fetch?

Comment: Probably this :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017576/what-is-the-difference-between-fetch-and-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 6):

This is how I made it work.

I added this line in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddAntiforgery(x => x.HeaderName = "X-ANTI-FORGERY-TOKEN");

    ...
}
```

Then I added the "X-ANTI-FORGERY-TOKEN" in the header of the fetch request:

```
let response = await fetch(form.action, {
        body: JSON.stringify(this.Json),
        method: form.method,
        headers: {
            "X-ANTI-FORGERY-TOKEN": document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0].value,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    });
```

Now it works like a charm.

Comment: I have been searching for weeks until I found you, much much appreciate my friend. This is exactly what I need. 
Please have a good life because you deserve it and Merry Christmas!