# Can't get ajax data, send with Post method to Django Views

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I tried to get/catch the data which is sent from ajax as the Post method. I believe data is sent properly cause I can see the send data in the console. I think I have issues with the view. Here is my code.

home.html

```
<script>
        document.getElementById('postForm').addEventListener('submit',postName);

        function postName(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var name = document.getElementById('id_name').value;
            var price = document.getElementById('id_price').value;
            var data = {
                'name':name,
                'price':price,
               
            }

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST',"{% url 'ajax-home' %}",true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
            var myData= JSON.stringify(data);
            xhr.onload = function(){
                console.log(myData);
            }
            
            xhr.send(myData);
        }

    </script>
```

views.py

```
def ajax_home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)

        if 'name' in request.POST:
            name = request.POST['name']
        else:
            name = "stil not found"    
        p = Product(name=name,price=100)
        p.save()
    
    else:
        form = ProductForm()
            
    products = Product.objects.all()

    context = {
        'form':form,
        'products': products}
    return render(request, 'myapp/home.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you send via your XHR request is not form data but a JSON string, hence `request.POST` will not contain those keys you expect it to contain. If you want to send the data as form data you should instead use [`FormData` [developer.mozilla.org]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData):

```
function postName(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = document.getElementById('id_name').value;
    var price = document.getElementById('id_price').value;
    var formData = new FormData(); // Create form data here
    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('price', price);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST',"{% url 'ajax-home' %}",true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
    
    xhr.send(formData); // Send form data
}
```

> **Note**: Consider using the [Fetch API [developer.mozilla.org]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)
> which is the modern alternative to `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your advice on Fetch API. I like to add one question in this comment, Is it better to use Ajax Jquery comparing to Fetch API? @Abdul Aziz Barkat

Comment: @Rubel see [What is the difference between fetch and jquery ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017576/what-is-the-difference-between-fetch-and-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a JSON string and trying to post that as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, below the data is constructed correctly

```
    function postName(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = document.getElementById('id_name').value;
        var price = document.getElementById('id_price').value;
        var data = 'name='+encodeURIComponent(name)='&price='+encodeURIComponent(price);
           
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST',"{% url 'ajax-home' %}",true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
        xhr.onload = function(){
            console.log(data);
        }
        xhr.send(data);
    }
```