# What is different between Fetch and jQuery Ajax post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch-api

I tried it as jQuery Ajax for post it work correctly.

Data will be hardcoded, but the **code** is one dynamic value.

```
const data = {
  "retrieve": {
   "header": {
    "userID": 'xxx',
   },
   "body": {
     "code": code,
     "channel" : []  
   }
  }
}
```

I use web **fetch** API to post, it failed.

```
const response = await fetch('https://api', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
const result = await response.json();
```

**Worked** if I use `$.ajax`

```
const response = await $.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  contentType: 'application/json'
})
```

Comment: When you say the native `fetch()` doesn't work, what is broken? What does your network tab say? Are there any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between fetch and jquery ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017576/what-is-the-difference-between-fetch-and-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

Both methods work, as you can see below. You forgot to add the `.then(r=>r.json())` decoding bit after the fetch request:

```js
const api="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
const data = {
  "retrieve": {
   "header": {
"userID": 'xxx',
   },
   "body": {
 "code": 4711,
 "channel" : [7,2,8,3]  
   }
  }
};

(async function(){
const res1 = await fetch(api, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(r=>r.json());
console.log("fetch:",res1);

const res2 = await $.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: api,
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  contentType: 'application/json'
});
console.log("jQuery Post:",res2);
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

It is important, however, that your backend implements these steps in order to make the fetch POST work:

- `$json=file_get_contents(php://input);` to receive the data in php
- decode it using `$data=json_decode($json);`

Comment: sorry, i didn't describe completely, i did to await the res.json. I updated the latest into post.