# Ajax in javascript return undefined

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this javascript function with ajax calling a .php calling a function inside a class .php, but the console.log is undefined

```
    function SpinTimeTotal(){
        $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url: "app/get_SpinTimeTotal.php",
       success: function($a){
            return $a;
        }
    });
    }

spinTimeTotal = SpinTimeTotal();
console.log(spinTimeTotal);    //undefined
```

calling this php code

```
<?php
include_once "read_spindata.php";
$a = read_data_spin :: read_Timespin();
?>
```

calling this function

```
<?php
class read_data_spin{
public static function read_Timespin(){
        try{
            $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=dbname", "user", "pass");
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            echo "Conexion fallida". $ex -> getMessage();
            die();
        }
        $spinTimeTotal = $conexion -> query("SELECT spinTimeTotal FROM data_ruleta ORDER BY id DESC limit 1");
        return $spinTimeTotal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your PHP code doesn't send a response. You need an`echo` in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

SpinTimeTotal() is an asynchronous function and this statement won't wait until executed.

```
spinTimeTotal = SpinTimeTotal();
```

You should instead use deferred objects or promises.

```
function SpinTimeTotal()
{
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "app/get_SpinTimeTotal.php",
        success: function($a)
        {
            return deferred.resolve($a);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Your actual function call would then be:

```
$.when(SpinTimeTotal()).then(function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I didn't understand the function call, could you explain it for me pls?

Comment: You should read about promises. Start here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ and here: https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Answer (score 0):

You need to `echo` the result in your php script like

```
<?php
include_once "read_spindata.php";
$a = read_data_spin :: read_Timespin();
echo $a;
?>
```

In most cases there will be more to return than just single value. Then JSON is the preferred format:

```
echo json_encode($resultObject);
```

And, of course, you need to change your Ajax call too, like:

```
    function SpinTimeTotal(){
        $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url: "app/get_SpinTimeTotal.php",
       success: function($a){
          console.log($a);
        }
    });
    }
```

Th `console.log` in your global scope will have been fired before the Ajax success function had done its job. And even then, the returned value cannot be picked up from the global scope.

The only way to "return" a result value from an AJAX function would be into an async function, see here for a working example: [What is different between Fetch and jQuery Ajax post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67865889/what-is-different-between-fetch-and-jquery-ajax-post/67866124#67866124)

Comment: What happens if you simply `echo 123;` in the PHP script? Is that picked up by your AJAX call?

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in

Answer (score -1):

try `$a` without `$`  , just `a`

```
function SpinTimeTotal(){
       $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url: "app/get_SpinTimeTotal.php",
       success: function(a){
            return a;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: undefined too :(

Comment: `$a` is a valid variable name in JavaScript.